# Position of direct object

Tags: grammar

Can the direct object ever precede the subject and verb? I know the direct object usually comes after the verb. I have researched the Internet, but have been unable to find a site that supports the direct object preceding the subject and verb. For example, A book I want. Would this be possible in prose? Poetic license might allow it in poetry.

Comment: Yes. It is called complement preposing.

Answer (score 1):

*Whether an object can be fronted* you want to know?

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_clause_syntax#Fronting_and_zeroing) you could look at.

Comment: I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: And, as well as giving you a link to where it is discussed, I answered with two examples of what you are asking.